# How to select files in one window and upload in another using html and PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

In my case a popup windows opens an a file is selected for upload. after it has been closed i have many files in the main window to upload. foe openning the window this is the code :

```
var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
var rv = window.open (URL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no,directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
//var rv = window.showModalDialog (URL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no,directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);    
return rv;
```

and this is the HTML content for the popup window :

```
<div>
  <input type='file' name='selectfile' id='selectfile' accept='.png'>
</div>
```

after the file is selected i need to send it back to the main window and close the popup window without uploading the file so the user can select as many as it can an updated the files once it has submitted the main form. the user might decide to remove some of the files before submitting the main window. my question is that is this scenario possible? and if it is, what do i need for the main form to be able to do so?

Comment: You might have to dive in to HTML5 to make that happen. But why are you doing it like this? And also, your HMTL is invalid (unless it is a typo).

Comment: thanks for the typo, I am using HTML5 in case there is something that I am not aware of, can you please explain more.

Comment: [HTML5 File API](http://www.google.com/search?q=HTML5+File+API)